# How to sort a composite aggregation on the basis of a sub aggregation ? Below is the query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, aws-elasticsearch

```
GET myIndex/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": {
              "value": "a88604b0",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "entity_status.keyword": {
              "value": "ACTIVE",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "txn_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "group_by": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "category"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am executing above query but I want the aggregations to be sorted by sub-aggregation 
`total_amount` in descending order. Any modification or other ways to achieve this ?

Here is the result of the above query.

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "successful" : 4,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 22,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_buckets" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "group_by" : "Travel"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "group_by" : "Bills"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "total_amount" : {
            "value" : 86710.44
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "group_by" : "Grocery"
          },
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total_amount" : {
            "value" : 43355.22
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "group_by" : "Fashion"
          },
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "total_amount" : {
            "value" : 216776.1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "group_by" : "Recharge"
          },
          "doc_count" : 7,
          "total_amount" : {
            "value" : 303486.54
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "group_by" : "Shopping"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "total_amount" : {
            "value" : 86710.44
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "group_by" : "Travel"
          },
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "total_amount" : {
            "value" : 216776.1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have the aggregations to be in sorted manner according to `total_amount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible right now. Each source can be ordered in ascending or descending order, but that's pretty much it.

Ordering by a sub-aggregation would require gathering all compound keys and computing the total amount for each bucket, which would be very costly in terms of memory and exactly the opposite of what the composite aggregation is trying to achieve, i.e. a way to paginate through buckets with a very low memory footprint

Also note that if you have a low cardinality of categories (<1000), you don't really need the composite aggregation, you can achieve what you need with the `terms` aggregation, like this:

```
{
  ...
  "aggs": {
    "group_by": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "total_amount": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanx for the insight , btw is there any way we can aggregate, sort and paginate (including sub-aggregation) in elasticsearch ? This was what I was trying to achieve through above query

Comment: You can do so (i.e. sort by sub-aggregations) with a simple bucket aggregations, like `terms` and `date_histogram` but not composite.

Comment: Currently, 25-30 category terms but can be increased in future to around 50.
Adding to the other comment, If I use ```terms``` or ```date_histogram``` then I can't achieve pagination I guess.